# Paypal button image broken

Tags: paypal

I have problem with paypal image, sometime it not display on my site

Here is URL

> https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&buttontype=ecmark&locale=nl_NL

the detail error

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /cgi-bin/dynamicimageweb was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>   Apache Server at fpdbs.paypal.com Port 443

I have magento site and I import that paypal payment. caused by this, my user can't see payment method logo

Have anyone same and succeeded to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with PayPal delivering those images. So there is not so much you can do about it other then downloading the image and embed it by yourself. Or even those another Paypal Image hosted by yourself.

But please before you do this read through Paypal if it is okay to A. Download the Image and host it by yourself. and B. If it is okay to host a different with the Paypal Trademark on it.

Comment: this image embed with payment method name and return from paypal payment 
So I can't change it